# how to get difference between two date_time

Tags: java

I want to get the difference in seconds between end_date_time and system_date_time using JAVA, for example:

```
if 
    end_date_time = 2015-02-21 13:00:00
    system_date_time = 2015-02-20 13:00:00
then 
    difference = 86400
```

Please tell how can I do this?

Comment: Really? None of the 65,812 hits when entering `java datetime difference site:stackoverflow.com` into Google were any good? If not, why would you expect the 65,813th to be any different? :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating the Difference Between Two Java Date Instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Date` type already, it's as simple as:

```
(System.currentTimeMillis() - myDate.getTime()) / 1000;
```

If you have a string and need to convert it to a date, you use a `SimpleDateFormat` instance:

```
String dateString = "2015-02-21 13:00:00" // end_date_time
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date myDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

If you're using Java8, this is much easier:

```
String dateString = "2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z";
Instant.now().until(Instant.parse(dateString), ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
```

Your `dateString` must be parseable in the ISO format, though:

```
"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SZ"
```

Comment: No not never. This doesn't account for drifts in dates cause by leap seconds, leap years, century and millennium boundaries. Use appropriate libraries, like JodaTime or java 8s new time API

Comment: You're correct. Added a reference to the Java8 method.